# Errors encountered while processing "grub-efi-amd64-signed" and "shim-signed" [Post upgrade from Ubuntu desktop 18.04 to 20.04]

Tags: grub2, uefi

After performing direct upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, everytime I install an application following errors are generated in the console:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.142+2.04-1ubuntu26) ... dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
  installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10 No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure. dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shim-signed:
  shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed | grub-efi-arm64-signed; however: 
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
   Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while processing:
  grub-efi-amd64-signed  shim-signed E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

However, the application is installed despite the error.

Answer (score 9):

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 19.10 to Ubuntu 20.04. I faced the same problem. The following solution worked for me:

```
# sudo apt-get purge grub\*
# sudo apt-get install grub-efi
# sudo apt-get autoremove
# sudo update-grub
```

This is something that is already discussed at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203528/errors-grub-efi-amd64-signed-shim-signed) link.

Comment: This has no chance of breaking the bootloader?

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar question in Stack Overflow, and some users report [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53284186/2123905) works fine.
Could you try and tell if it worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered 2 causes for this problem.

### 1. dpkg bug from 2020-04-09

There was a bug in dpkg on 2020-04-09 [#1871963 dpkg fails to install grub-efi-amd64 signed and shim-signed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1871963)  which may have been causing this problem, due to an extraneous `;;` in the post install script. The error you'd see is:

`/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-efi-amd64-signed.postinst: 23: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`

### 2. missing /boot/efi mount

If booting with EFI, the EFI boot partition [must be correctly mounted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405525/585078). What finally fixed it for me, was to ensure that `/boot` and `/boot/efi` were mounted to different partitions (and the correct ones). Installation of `grub-efi-amd64-signed` will fail if your EFI partition is not mounted at `/boot/efi`.

Machines will vary, but my mount points ended up like this:

```
$ lsblk | grep -E "nvme|sdb"
sdb1       ...  1G   part  /boot
nvme0n1p2  ...  99M  part  /boot/efi
```

which gives a file structure like this, with the kernel images in `/boot`, and the main `EFI` folder under `/boot/efi/EFI`

```
/boot$ tree -L 3
.
├── config-4.14.248
├── config-4.14.248.old
├── config-5.4.0-150-generic
├── config-5.4.0-87-generic
├── efi
│   ├── EFI
│   │   ├── Boot
│   │   ├── Microsoft
│   │   └── ubuntu
│   └── System Volume Information
├── grub
│   ├── fonts
│   ...
│   └── x86_64-efi
│       ├── acpi.mod
│       ├── adler32.mod
│       ...
│       ├── zfs.mod
│       └── zstd.mod
├── initrd.img-4.14.248
├── initrd.img-4.14.248-surface-linux-surface.signed
├── initrd.img-5.4.0-150-generic
├── initrd.img-5.4.0-87-generic
...
```

The root cause was `dpkg` not finding the `/boot/efi/EFI` directory, and that directory not being a correct EFI/vfat file system. Root cause of the error is this:

```
`dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure)`
```

Once I had /boot/efi mounted correctly, all these errors went away.

Answer (score 0):

it didnt worked, but i tried to delete the grub file in etc/default/ mannually (with admin rights) and i went to terminal and i entered

> sudo apt-get install grub-efi

It worked then! (:

Comment: What didn't work? Swaggat's answer?

Comment: Details please. As written this is not an answer. Seems you are addressing another question not this one.