# Error when upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade

I got this final error when I upgraded from 21.10 to 22.04 LTS:

```
root@reaper /opt # apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.180+2.06-2ubuntu7) ...
mount: /var/lib/grub/esp: special device /dev/sda15 does not exist.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 32
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed | grub-efi-arm64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
  Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful as its bugging me at the moment.

Thanks,
Salvo

Comment: Something went wrong during the upgrade. The short pain: perform a fresh install using installation media, replacing your current installation. That constitutes kind of a spring cleanup at the same time.

Comment: I would love to be able to do that, but it's a "production" system with many docker images running, so I cannot just fresh install it at a moment's notice. I am hoping someone else can offer some more advice on where to look to try and fix it. Thanks for the helpful suggestion!

Comment: Turn off/disable 'secure boot' in UEFI ( what some people incorrectly still call BIOS). Then try the upgrade again.

Comment: I managed to resolve it by running:

`apt remove shim-signed grub-efi-amd64-bin --allow-remove-essential`

We don't use secure boot, so your solution was a good one @JoepieEs

Comment: Great. So you can answer your own question and in 2 days you can accept your answer by ticking the grey V on the left side of the answer. By doing this community members can see that the question is solved. If you want you can tick the arrow up next to my comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to resolve it by running: `apt remove shim-signed grub-efi-amd64-bin --allow-remove-essential`

There was no EFI system on the server, confirmed by `fdisk -l`

Comment: For anyone like me who don’t know how to check for EFI with `fdisk -l`, note there’s a simpler solution: check if `/sys/firmware/efi` exists on your system ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/162896/207702)).

Comment: What's the solution if the EFI system does exist?

Comment: @NublicPablo - In case related to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231781/errors-encountered-while-processing-grub-efi-amd64-signed-and-shim-signed-p). I don't have efi but had that problem. Trying to fix it, it was reduced to the above problem.