# dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure): Errors were encountered while processing: grub-efi-amd64-signed shim-signed

Tags: apt, dpkg, 22.04, grub-efi

I get the below errors when I hit `sudo apt upgrade`. I am unable to fix the error. Any help, please?

```
root@Ubuntu-2204-jammy-amd64-base ~ # sudo apt upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Try Ubuntu Pro beta with a free personal subscription on up to 5 machines.
Learn more at https://ubuntu.com/pro
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.182~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu10) ...
mount: /var/lib/grub/esp: special device /dev/sda15 does not exist.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 32
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed | grub-efi-arm64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
  Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Seeing the same problem here after `sudo apt upgrade`. Noticed four packages which were being held back the other day, now they installed and broke dpkg. Tried the solutions outlined [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1871963/comments/13) for Focal, but no luck.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot install new packages because of this issue.

Comment: I tried https://askubuntu.com/a/1407132/560505 removing the packages and it works. You should check first if you have secure boot enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Doing `sudo apt dist-upgrade` is solving my problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1343334)