# How to migrate from 22.04 LTS to 23.10?

Tags: 22.04, lts, migration, 23.10

22.04 LTS is in use with 6.5 oem kernel and KDE from kubuntu repo. Is there a way to migrate to 23.10?

Comment: Currently the *release-upgrade* path from 22.04 is to Ubuntu 23.04 or the next release in the next cycle (*Ubuntu development is a two year cycle ending in the LTS; 22.10, 23.04 & 23.10 are part of the development cycle that will end with release of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS*).  The upgrade path will switch from 22.04 to 23.10 when Ubuntu 23.04 reaches EOL in about three months.

Comment: The migration path from 22.04 to 23.04 (or 23.10) is possible, but not much tested by the community. Be prepared for limited support if you encounter problems due to that limited testing. Be prepared to reinstall in case the worst occurs. Backup your data before starting the migration, of course.

Comment: I wrote a guide and also created a video about [how to upgrade Ubuntu from 22.04 to 23.10](https://sypalo.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu)

Comment: @user535733 - At the date of the question (Oct. 2023) 22.04>23.04 was already possible with `sudo do-release-upgrade`. I have just upgraded from 22.04 (kubuntu) to 23.10 directly now (because, as Guiverc said, 23.04 reached end of standard support [in January 2024](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle)).

Comment: @cipricus, The point user535733 made (*as I understood it*) is mostly that it receives little to no QA testing, and that is something I totally concur with (*I didn't know the upgrade path existed until bdmurray/Brian Murray corrected me; we at Lubuntu don't QA for it*).  Ubuntu CI testing occurs for that path for sure, but that's less than CI+QA tested intended paths.

Comment: @guiverc - I am happy to have tested and to confirm it works!

Comment: @cipricus  :)   great response !

Comment: @cipricus glad you encountered success on that particular migration path. Good support comes from folks like you, who push the envelope and are willing to share.

Comment: @user535733 - After 24.04 is released, what would `do-release-upgrade` do on a system before 23.10? Given that 23.10 is supported until July, it would still be "the next supported" release before that. So `do-release-upgrade` is not usable for LTS>LTS upgrade?

Comment: @cipricus the [Ubuntu Release Upgrader](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-release-upgrader) tool use this file (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release) to determine what *release-upgrades* are available; even on release no change is made to that file. An upgrade from 22.04 won't open until AFTER 24.04.1 has been released (*and that file is often modified days/weeks later when the Ubuntu Release Team decide its ready & all testing is good*). If `-d` is also used this file (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development) is used instead..  How that file is read varies on your release.

Comment: @guiverc - Which means that `-d` allows testing 24.04 already! Nice. (I've read and even tested for a while in neon unstable that even Plasma 6 is rather stable, so testing Kubuntu 24.04, which keeps to 5.27, shouldn't be too risky.)

Comment: @cipricus  Ubuntu *noble* is still in *alpha* which means problems can be experienced...  I've been using it approaching four months, and I'm very aware of *apps* that won't run due to a known issue (eg. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/2046844)  which I'm using here as example only... The warnings about *alpha* and *beta* software are there for a reason... which doesn't mean all users experience issues; but also don't forget sites like this are off-topic if you're using the *development* release.

Comment: @user535733 - For reference, on pushing the envelope: I ended up with [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1406375/925128) problem after the upgrade, although this is a non-efi laptop. Fixed it as in the [answer thereunder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406375/error-when-upgrading-to-ubuntu-22-04-lts/1407132#1407132).

Comment: @guiverc - Trying to test 24.04, I could not because any upgrade triggered [this error](https://askubuntu.com/q/1406375/925128). I have fixed that, but the obvious probability of annoying accidents has persuaded me to stay put for now :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu supports two safe migration paths: from LTS to LTS version (e.g. 20.04 -> 22.04) or to the next higher STS Version. So, in the given case, you would need to follow this update path: 22.04 -> 22.10 -> 23.04 -> 23.10.

Comment: The [Ubuntu release upgrader tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) was modified awhile back to all *release-upgrade* to the next *supported* release in the next cycle as per my prior comment. Yes to the next release was the *supported* path long ago, but when 22.10 became EOL the path your answer assumes is gone, thus the change of allowing 22.04 to 23.04 as will now occur...  If a 22.04 user performs `do-release-upgrade` now, they'll move to 23.04 (skipping 22.10); when 23.04 is EOL they'll go straight to 23.10.

Comment: I did 22.04->23.04 and I'm doing 23.04->23.10, I hope I didn't mess up anything doing so.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO - Waiting a few days more and 22.04>23.10 would have been possible directly.

Comment: `or to next higher STS Version`: I think that is incorrect. The alternative to LTS>LTS is not to *next higher* (like 22.04>22.10), but to the *next supported* release: 22.10 had already ceased being supported at the date of the OP question (and of your answer: Oct. 2023), but 23.04 still was. It's not anymore at the date of my comment here, when upgrade to 23.10 can be done with `do-release-upgrade`. By the way, `do-release-upgrade -d` can already do a direct upgrade to yet unrealeased 24.04.

Answer (score 5):

Running `do-release-upgrade -c` will show which next release is *directly* accessible for upgrade.

At the date of the question (Oct. 2023) `sudo do-release-upgrade` would have only upgraded 22.04 to 23.04 (as per [comment by @FLAK-ZOSO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1489052/how-to-migrate-from-22-04-lts-to-23-10?noredirect=1#comment2627246_1489054)), that is: to the *next supported* version. But 23.04 reached end of standard support [in January 2024](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle), therefore now (February 2024) 23.10 is the next supported one, so upgrade 22.04>23.10 is possible.

I can confirm myself this works now, as indicated in [comment by @guiverc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1489052/how-to-migrate-from-22-04-lts-to-23-10?noredirect=1#comment2608242_1489052).

Answer (score 0):

You can fresh install Ubuntu 23.10 by downloading the ISO and flashing it to a  USB drive.

Otherwise, wait for 24.04 LTS to be released (April 2024). You will be able to upgrade to that directly.

Comment: The OP asks for upgrade to 23.10. That is now (February 2024) possible directly from 22.04 because 23.04 has reached end of support.

Comment: @cipricus It was not a valid upgrade path when I answered the question

Comment: You are right, but the path 22.04>23.04>23.10 was I think.